Flutter: ListView with header
Created custom header
  Widget _listHeader({bool hideSelect = true}) {
    return Container(
      color: headerColor,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: hideSelect,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                context.tr(
                    TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kSelect, TcTrValues.kSelect),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                context.tr(TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kDocumentType,
                    TcTrValues.kDocumentType),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                context.tr(TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kSurveyNo,
                    TcTrValues.kSurveyNo),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                context.tr(
                    TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kPageNo, TcTrValues.kPageNo),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

ListView Item builder widget
 Widget newItems(SelectedSurveyModel item, bool showCheckBox, int index,
      {bool showDelete = false}) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      VP(size: Dimens.d10.responsive()),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
            visible: showCheckBox,
            child: QCheckBox(
              value: item.isSelected,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    if (widget.feeList == null) {
                      item.isSelected = value;
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
                padding: showCheckBox
                    ? EdgeInsets.all(0)
                    : EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Text(
                  '${item.documentName}',
                )),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Text(
              '${item.khasraNo}',
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Text(
              ' ${item.pageNo}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: showDelete,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_outline_rounded),
              onPressed: () {
                if (widget.feeList == null) {
                  _onDeleteItem(index);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }

calling _header() widget just above ListView.Builder but having alignment issues

I also tried with DataTable.
With using DataTable.
  List<DataColumn> _createColumns() {
    return [
      DataColumn(
          label: Text(context.tr(
              TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kSelect, TcTrValues.kSelect))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text(context.tr(TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kDocumentType,
              TcTrValues.kDocumentType))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text(context.tr(
              TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kSurveyNo, TcTrValues.kSurveyNo))),
      DataColumn(
          label: Text(context.tr(
              TcConstants.moduleId, TcTrKeys.kPageNo, TcTrValues.kPageNo))),
    ];
  }

  List<DataRow> _createRows() {
    return tmpSelectedSurvey
        .map((item) => DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(QCheckBox(
                value: item.isSelected,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      if (widget.feeList == null) {
                        item.isSelected = value;
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
              )),
              DataCell(Text(
                ' ${item.documentName}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
              DataCell(Text(
                ' ${item.khasraNo}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
              DataCell(Text(
                ' ${item.pageNo}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ]))
        .toList();
  }

Getting this..

Want to achieve this with ListView.Builder


Please explain the exact issue of alignment you want to fix. is it the value of column 2 and 3 not below the header titles?

Try below code hope its help to you.
Using ListView.builder()
Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.green.shade300,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 30,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Text('Select document type'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('Survey Number'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text('Page Number'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (child, index) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 4,
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                        title: const Text('Select member name'),
                        value: false,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text('2'),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text('8, 9, 10'),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),

Result: 
Using DataTable
Declaration:
static const int numItems = 25;
List<bool> selected = List<bool>.generate(numItems, (int index) => false);

UI:
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: DataTable(
    columnSpacing: 10,
    headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green.shade300),
    columns: const <DataColumn>[
      DataColumn(
        label: Expanded(
          child: Text('Select document type'),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Expanded(
          child: Text('Survey Number'),
        ),
      ),
      DataColumn(
        label: Expanded(
          child: Text('Page Number'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
    rows: List<DataRow>.generate(
      numItems,
      (int index) => DataRow(
        cells: <DataCell>[
          DataCell(Text('Member Name')),
          DataCell(Center(child: Text('2'))),
          DataCell(Center(child: Text('8,9,10'))),
        ],
        selected: selected[index],
        onSelectChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            selected[index] = value!;
            print(index);
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
),

Result: 
